# Replace column values of sliced rows with None in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
colA colB colC
12    33  66
13    35  67
14    44  77 
15    55  79
18    56  81
```

I would like to replace the values of colB and colC with None starting from index 2 all the way to the end of df. The expected output is:

```
colA colB   colC
12    33    66
13    35    67
14    None  None 
15    None  None
18    None  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with any index and columns names in list:

```
df.loc[df.index[2:], ['colB','colC']] = None
```

If there is default `RangeIndex` use `2:`:

```
df.loc[2:, ['colB','colC']] = None
print (df)
   colA  colB  colC
0    12  33.0  66.0
1    13  35.0  67.0
2    14   NaN   NaN
3    15   NaN   NaN
4    18   NaN   NaN
```

Because numeric values are `None`s converted to `NaN`s.

If need integers with missing values use [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df[['colB','colC']] = df[['colB','colC']].astype('Int64')
print (df)

   colA  colB  colC
0    12    33    66
1    13    35    67
2    14  <NA>  <NA>
3    15  <NA>  <NA>
4    18  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
df.loc[2:, "colB":] = None
```

Basically using the loc method to select the rows starting from index 2 and the columns colB and colC, and then assign the value None to them. This will replace the values of colB and colC with None starting from index 2.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) ([that jezrael's mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74771320/7109869)), one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) as follows

```
df.iloc[2:, 1:] = None

[Out]:

   colA  colB  colC
0    12  33.0  66.0
1    13  35.0  67.0
2    14   NaN   NaN
3    15   NaN   NaN
4    18   NaN   NaN
```

Note that `colB` and `colC` are floats, because `NaN` is a float. If one doesn't want those columns to be `float64`, one approach would be to use [`pandas.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) as follows

```
df[['colB', 'colC']] = df[['colB', 'colC']].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
  
[Out]:

   colA  colB  colC
0    12    33    66
1    13    35    67
2    14  <NA>  <NA>
3    15  <NA>  <NA>
4    18  <NA>  <NA>
```